# tar delete progress not shown?

Tags: command-line, tar

I was trying to use tar command , --delete option and met some problems. There are two things I don't understand:

when using `--verbose` option with combination of `--delete` option, nothing shows as --verbose usually do, i.e. no show of deleted files.
when using `--totals` option, the deleted size is always 0, it doesn't make sense and I can't figure out the meaning of these output.

Can anyone help me with these? The following code shows the procedure.

```
x@x:~/bin$ tar --list --file=pomo.tar
pomodoro
pomodoro_2
pomodoro_3
x@x:~/bin$ tar --append --file=pomo.tar quitpomo --verbose
quitpomo
x@x:~/bin$ tar --list --file=pomo.tar
pomodoro
pomodoro_2
pomodoro_3
quitpomo
x@x:~/bin$ tar --list --file=pomo.tar --totals
pomodoro
pomodoro_2
pomodoro_3
quitpomo
Total bytes read: 10240 (10KiB, 12MiB/s)
x@x:~/bin$ tar --delete --file=pomo.tar quitpomo --total --verbose
Total bytes read: 10240 (10KiB, 86MiB/s)
Total bytes written: 10240 (10KiB, 86MiB/s)
Total bytes deleted: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into `man tar` for clues?!

> **NAME**
>     tar — The GNU version of the tar archiving utility
>
> **SYNOPSIS**
>      tar [-] A --catenate --concatenate | c --create | d --diff --compare |
>            --delete | r --append | t --list | --test-label | u --update | x
>            --extract --get [options] [pathname ...]
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>      Tar stores and extracts files from a tape or disk archive.

```
 The first argument to tar should be a function; either one of the letters
 Acdrtux, or one of the long function names.  A function letter need not be
 prefixed with ``-'', and may be combined with other single-letter options.
 A long function name must be prefixed with --.  Some options take a param‐
 eter; with the single-letter form these must be given as separate argu‐
 ments.  With the long form, they may be given by appending =value to the
 option.
```